# Jquery/Javascript text slider loop running on setTimeout breaks when you leave the tab.

Tags: javascript

Here is the website: esanexpharma.com.
The divs are both using absolute positioning.

Here is the code:

```
    var heroTextShow = function() {
      jQuery('.hero-1').fadeIn().delay(5000).fadeOut();
      jQuery('.hero-2').delay(5300).fadeIn(500).delay(2000).fadeOut();
      setTimeout(heroTextShow, 8700);
    };

    heroTextShow();
```

The code runs fine unless you got to another tab and then comeback in which case some sort of timing error is happening. I have also tried running this on a setInterval but ran into the exact same problem. Any insight would be appreciated.

Comment: you want it to run in a loop? It works on my machine, but the second text fades in too quickly

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout#Timeouts_in_inactive_tabs_throttled_to_>1000ms

Comment: Yeah, i'm not so much worried about that. The problem i'm having is that if i navigate to another tab in chrome and come back say 30 seconds later i'm getting multiple instances of the loop running. Or at least something that is causing both divs to be displayed on top each other at every other h1 that is displayed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [@ryanpcmcquen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2662028/ryanpcmcquen) said in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45744079/1913729), timeouts may be throttled when the tab becomes inactive.

The problem here is that you have multiple concurrent timers (jQuery's ones for `.hero-1` and `.hero-2`, and your `setTimeout`). When you switch tabs, these timers may overlap.

To avoid this, you could chain your animations, and you'll always have just one timer running at a time. This way, even if it gets slowed down, it will never overlap *(Note that I added a common class `.hero` for both divs)*:

```js
var heroTextShow = function() {
  var elements = $('.hero'),
      total    = elements.length,
      index    = 0;

  (function next() {
    elements.eq(index)
            .fadeIn(500)
            .delay(5000)
            .fadeOut(200, function() {
                index++;
                if (index >= total) { index = 0; }
                next();
            });
  })();
};

heroTextShow();
```

```css
.hero { position: absolute; top: 1rem; left: 1rem; display: none; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="hero">11111111111111</div>
<div class="hero">2222222222222</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Inactive tabs will have `setTimeout()` calls modified. From MDN:

> Timeouts in inactive tabs throttled to >=1000ms
>
> To reduce the load (and associated battery usage) from background
>   tabs, timeouts are throttled to firing no more often than once per
>   second (1000 ms) in inactive tabs.
>
> Firefox implements this behavior since version 5 (see bug 633421, the
>   1000ms constant can be tweaked through the
>   dom.min_background_timeout_value preference). Chrome implements this
>   behavior since version 11 (crbug.com/66078).
>
> Firefox for Android uses a timeout value of 15 minutes for background
>   tabs since bug 736602 in Firefox 14, and background tabs can also be
>   unloaded entirely.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout#Timeouts_in_inactive_tabs_throttled_to_>1000ms

Answer (score 0):

jQuery uses short timed intervals internally. If the intervals are getting longer ( if you leave the tab ) , youre getting into race problems. May just using one timer ( the jquery one) could help:

```
(function heroTextShow() {

  jQuery('.hero-1').clearQueue().fadeIn().delay(5000).fadeOut();
  jQuery('.hero-2').delay(5300).fadeIn(500).delay(2000).fadeOut("slow",/*then*/ heroTextShow);

})();
```